# Context Menu of TableView in Child Widget

Tags: qt, uitableview, signals-slots

I am programming in C++ in QT and trying to make a UI with dynamic tabs having tables inside each of them. For doing the same, I had my TabWidget in the main window, and another widget with just the tableView. As the tabs are dynamically being added to the main window by a button click, I make a new object of my widget and put it in that.

I also have another version of the application in which there are no tabs, just a tableView in the main window.

I am unable to open the context menu in the former case, while it works perfectly for the latter.

I am using the signal "customContextMenuRequested" in both the cases. Don't understand what I need to add for it to work when the tableView is in a child widget.

Some help please? 
Thanks already!

Comment: Did you use the `mapToGlobal` function of the view to correctly display the popup menu and have you checked if the signal triggers a slot? Is the context menu policy of the view set to `CustomContextMenu`?

Comment: The `mapToGlobal` is set correctly and the policy is set to `CustomContextMenu`. It's the signal which is not triggering the slot.

Comment: I never had any problems with this. Can you provide more information or small sample code that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: Okay, so I had added the actions to my context menu in a function which also set the model of the tableView. I moved the code to the constructor of the child widget instead, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that nothing is involving QAbstractScrollArea, it's possible that in this case it would signal/slot as expected.

> This signal is emitted when the widget's contextMenuPolicy is Qt::CustomContextMenu, and the user has requested a context menu on the widget. The position pos is the position of the context menu event that the widget receives. Normally this is in widget coordinates. The exception to this rule is QAbstractScrollArea and its subclasses that map the context menu event to coordinates of the viewport() .